# WildFly 8.2.0, JBossWS using reverse proxy generates incorrect https soap:address

Tags: soap, wsdl, reverse-proxy, wildfly, jbossws

My setup is a apache server on https acting as a reverse proxy to WildFly 8.2.0 responding on port 8080. The web service is created using the bottom up approach via annotations. The soap:address that is generated does not have the correct protocol or port. I have modified the standalone.xml to specify the wsdl-host and allow modification of the WSDL URL. The webservices subsystem are as follows:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
    <wsdl-host>myhost.com</wsdl-host>
    <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
    <wsdl-secure-port>443</wsdl-secure-port>
    <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
    <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
        <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
            <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
        </pre-handler-chain>
    </endpoint-config>
    <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
</subsystem>
```

The generated wsdl contains:

```
<wsdl:port binding="tns:HelloServiceSoapBinding" name="HelloServicePort">
    <soap:address location="http://myhost.com:8080/pfdemo/HelloService"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

I was expecting location="https://myhost.com/pfdemo/HelloService"/>

I thought specifying the wsdl-secure-port and allowing the modify-wsdl-address would take care of the protocol and port, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I correct the protocol and port in the soap:address for the generated wsdl?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add

```
<wsdl-uri-scheme>https</wsdl-uri-scheme>
```

This property explicitly sets the URI scheme to use for rewriting .

Valid values are http and https.

This configuration overrides scheme computed by processing the endpoint (even if a transport guarantee 
is specified).

The provided values for wsdl-port and wsdl-secure-port (or their default values) are used depending on specified scheme.

*source*: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/JBWS/Published+WSDL+customization